# POST method on Node.js won't work on Replit server with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to backend and I'm using Node.js in a Replit server with express to deploy an application of files:

However, when I try to perform a post nothing happens!

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var fs = require('fs');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();

    // Middlewares 
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.post('/foo.json', function (req, res) {
        console.log("It doesn't work!");
    });
```

All I want to do is to save data collected from index.html to a .json through POST method of express (I'm not sure it's the best approach). What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above is not for making requests

```
   app.post('/foo.json', function (req, res) {
        console.log("It does not work");
    });
```

This means that you are accepting requests on `http://your_url/foo.json`

It is an endpoint.

For what you are trying to do, you have to make a request from the frontend using `xhr` or libraries like `axios`

```
# Axios CDN:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

axios.post('http://localhost:3002/foo', {
  data: 'your_data_goes_here'
})
```

Your backend code should be

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const PORT = 3002;

// Middlewares 
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/foo', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.data);
});

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {

    //  CORS
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //  Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    //  Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET','POST', 'OPTIONS');

    next();
});

// Start the app
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Oh. But where should I put this piece of code?? In the "server javascript" ?

Comment: You can have a `.js` file at the frontend to make the request.

Comment: Right. And that "axios" how may I require it ??

Comment: You can load it via CDNs. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now when I try to perform post, I get 404. Do u have any thoughts ?
isAxiosError.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (isAxiosError.js:10)

Comment: Because your server is not listening for connections. Check the updated answer. Also, use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: @AvivLo using `const` or `let` isn't really relevant to this issue.

Comment: Yes. It's not. It was intended to be a side note.

Comment: I can't find where I posted json. I access /foo and nothing

Comment: Just updated the answer. To be clear, you send your json data via post requests using axios, the server will log it. But how it is going to write it to files, you gotta read the Nodejs documentation about `fs`

Comment: Ok. It's fine. Thank you for improving your answer and helping me 'til now. One more thing. "foo" is the API? I have not configurated any. I have just the index.html, main.js, node.js files. I see from Dev tools that the request is being sent, but it's not going anywhere.

Comment: Yes. `http://localhost:3002/foo` is the API end point. If you check the server log in your text editor/IDE, you should see your data being logged because of the `console.log(req.body.data);` You can decide whatever you want to do with the data in the `app.post(...)` function.